# Logitch 9000 with Ubuntu

Tags: skype, webcam

I have a Logitech 9000 Pro which works fine with Wi.10 and Win.7 and also works with both OSs in Skype. However, I now wish to use it with Ubuntu, which I downloaded a couple of days ago (I think vers. 20.04, the newest version). I have checked with lsbusb and the camera is listed. I do not seem to be able to install it in Ubuntu, nor can I install in via Skype. I am a newcomer to Ubuntu, just having familiarised myself with the CLI. Do I need extra software (e.g. Cheese, whatever that is?). If anyone could give me some clear (and hopefully simple) instructions, I should be most grateful.

Comment: Are you saying the camera doesn't work in Skype on Ubuntu? You don't need Cheese, but it is a very simple program that will use your camera if it's available. If it works in Cheese it should work in Skype.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.I haven't downloaded Cheese, I didn't really understand its function. I just saw it mentioned in connection with the problem. Incidentally, the software that I downloaded from Logitech was intended for a newer webcam than 9000 Pro, which is no longer supported, but it works.
When I run lsusb I see the following line:
 Bus 001 Device 003:ID 046d:0809 Logitech, Inc webcam Pro 0000.That looks promising.

I have to confess that I am not yet very familiar with the operation of Ubuntu/Linux. The CLI commands look very similar to DOS! Do most people use the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

Just to try to end this account, let me say that, in desperation, I finally just installed the Skype software. Then I simply plugged in the Logitech 9000 Pro and, to my great surprise, the camera was detected  immediately by the software. So, absolutely no need to install the webcam beforehand or fiddle about trying to install any Logitech software.
Thanks to anyone who takes the effort to read this!